# Why is Redis middleware breaking my routes?

Tags: javascript, express, redis, routes

After extensive testing I removed my Redis sessions and replaced with basis sessions.  After this my routes began working.

I am behind a firewall which will not allow my Redis to connect.  How can I fix this so I can still test my routes even when Redis is blocked by a firewall?

Why is Redis even being used for simple routes

```
// module.exports.session = session({
//   secret: 'foomanchoo',
//   resave: false,
//   saveUninitialized: true,
//   store: new RedisStore({ client: RedisClient, host: 'localhost', port: 6379})
// });


module.exports.session = session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat'
});
```

I am using a simple test route as follows:

```
app.get('/foo', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello I am an express server at /foo');  
});
```

Comment: Why *would* it work with Redis sessions if Redis can't connect? Switch the provider for local development or provide Redis locally.

Comment: I need to do a tutorial on Redis.  It thought sessions were for sending and receiving user data.  What do sessions have to do with sending a string of text?